# MS SQL ASP.NET Dates Showing in "Wrong" Culture Format

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I developed an application in ASP.NET with MS SQL on a US based server. 
Once the app was deployed to a server somewhere in Europe the dates are displayed in Dutch format.

US application displays: **March 6, 2018**
European application displays: **maart 6, 2018**

The US Sql Server is 2012 and the European SQL Server is 2014.

I've compared the SQL Server settings and there is only one difference I can find...

US SQL Server Collation = SQL_Latin1_General_CP1251_CI_AS
Europe SQL Server Collation = SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

I don't believe collation is the issue because I changed my US based server to match the European collation and there was no change in date format.

In C# I display the dates like this...

```
Convert.ToDateTime(mySQLTable.Rows[0]["datecompleted"]).ToString("MMMM d, yyyy");
```

The data in field "datecompleted" (DateTime) is identical on both servers.
I compared the HTML source code of both applications (View Source) and they are identical.
I can't see any difference in IIS either.

Any ideas where I should look to determine why one server is displaying dates in Dutch and the other in English?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to use `InvariantCulture` if you don't want `.ToString()` to use the current culture information from the machine.

Comment: Are you perhaps forcing the Dutch localization somewhere, like in the Web.config: `<globalization uiCulture="nl" culture="nl-NL"/>` This can also be done programatically somewhere.

Comment: Web.config does not contain any globalization settings

Comment: @MarkBenningfield both sites in IIS > .NET Globalization are set to:  Culture: Invariant Language and UI Culture: Invariant Language. Is that what you were referring to?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not positive that the IIS settings will override the culture information at the OS level, which is where `CurrentCulture` is specified. It's easy enough to check -> just add `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to the call.

Comment: I'm trying adding it to my C# when I display dates. Didn't know about it until you mentioned it so thanks! Will update my post once I'm done experimenting...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mark Benningfield this has been resolved...

I needed to add `InvariantCulture` to my C#

```
using System.Globalization;
...
Convert.ToDateTime(mySQLTable.Rows[0]["datecompleted"]).ToString("MMMM d, yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Now my date displays properly!